# Prove that $f'(1)\ge n \left ( 1+ \sqrt[n]{f(0)} \right)^{n-1}$

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)=(x+a_1)(x+a_2)...(x+a_n)$, where $a_1,a_2, ..., a_n -$ non-negative numbers. Prove that
$$f'(1)\ge n \left ( 1+ \sqrt[n]{f(0)} \right)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the product rule
$$\frac{f'(1)}{f(1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k+1}$$

The inequality you want to prove is:
$$ \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k+1} \right) (1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)\geq  n\left ( 1+ \sqrt[n]{a_1...a_n} \right)^{n-1}$$

Since by AM-GM you have
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k+1} \right) \geq \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)}}$$

If you can prove that
$$\left( \sqrt[n]{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)} \right)^{n-1} \geq \left ( 1+ \sqrt[n]{a_1...a_n} \right)^{n-1}$$ you are done.

This is equivalent to 
$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n) \geq \left ( 1+ \sqrt[n]{a_1...a_n} \right)^{n} $$

Now, write $a_j=b_j^n$. The inequality becomes
$$(1+b_1^n)(1+b_2^n)...(1+b_n^n) \geq \left ( 1+ b_1b_2..b_n \right)^{n} $$

which I think can be proven easily by opening the brackets and using AM-GM, but might follow even faster from something like Minkowski or Holder inequality.